# Postgres restore/update with WAL on cloned VM instead of using basebackup

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, wal

**Enviroment:** 800GB Postgres-Database (OpenSuse)

**Normal Restore-Process:**

- You have pg_basebackup to restore (from let's say: every Saturday)
- You have **WAL** files from last Saturday to today
- First: Restore with pg_basebackup
- Then: Update database with **WAL**-files to have newest data. (with recovery.conf)

**My Idea:**
Why do every week big pg_basebackup and copy 800GB over Internet to NAS, when you have everyday incremental Backups with some backup-software.

- Restore complete database-vm (stand yesterday)
- Add WAL-files (restore) to bring this vm-clone up to date.

Now i've done:

- I restored a vm
- create recovery.conf

  restore_command = 'cp /.../%f %p'
- rcpostgresql start

I get following errors:

```
2017-05-09 16:46:07.780 CEST [2938]: [1-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-05-09 16:45:47 CEST
2017-05-09 16:46:07.780 CEST [2938]: [2-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  starting archive recovery
2017-05-09 16:46:08.588 CEST [2952]: [1-1] user=[unknown],db=[unknown],app=[unknown],client=[local] LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2017-05-09 16:46:08.588 CEST [2952]: [2-1] user=postgres,db=postgres,app=[unknown],client=[local] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2017-05-09 16:46:09.391 CEST [2938]: [3-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  restored log file "000000010000070D0000008A" from archive
2017-05-09 16:46:09.434 CEST [2938]: [4-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  contrecord is requested by 70D/8A000028
2017-05-09 16:46:09.434 CEST [2938]: [5-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint record
2017-05-09 16:46:09.434 CEST [2938]: [6-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  invalid secondary checkpoint link in control file
2017-05-09 16:46:09.434 CEST [2938]: [7-1] user=,db=,app=,client= PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
2017-05-09 16:46:09.434 CEST [2936]: [4-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  startup process (PID 2938) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
2017-05-09 16:46:09.434 CEST [2936]: [5-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
```

After **pg_resetxlog** the next WAL-file was restored. and i get same error (with next wal-file-name)

Is there any way to get this working?

Comment: So long as you are calling `pg_start_backup()` and `pg_stop_backup()`, your incremental backup covers all database files and you have all the WAL files from pg_start_backup onwards this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days, I was able to get this working.
@Vao Tsun 's help bring me into right direction, but sadly wasn't necessary.

**How you can restore Postgres-Database with WAL-Files and complete VM Backup | Restore:**

- **backup:**

  - [ Maybe create a new postgres checkpoint. for me it was not necessary but my last checkpoint wasn't too old; for checkpoints there is a direct way without pg_start_backup() ]
  - Do a simple backup of your VM containing the postgres-database. full/incremental -> your choice. (I do this while VM was running)
  - `select pg_start_backup('some label')` is **NOT** necessary.
    Just normal backup with [maybe a checkpoint before]
- **restore VM:**

  - Do **NOT** boot this VM automatically. You need to make sure **postgres doesn't start automatically**. You can do this with special boot mode if you have, rename postgres binary or data-directory with live-linux-CD or having a script, which checks if system was restored so postgres should not start.
  - Boot VM
  - [ Maybe check pg_log-File if disabling postgres work. -> no new log file ]
- **restore database:**

  - create the recovery.conf inside the $pgdata directory:
    `restore_command = 'cp /[path_to_your_wal_backups]/%f "%p"'
    recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'`
  - start postgres
  - see pg_log if restoring of wal files worked
  - [ connect to database. and search for new data as last test ]

Answer (score 0):

From your error I **assume** you skipped `pg_start_backup`. Otherwise you [should have missing checkpoint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html):

> pg_start_backup accepts an arbitrary user-defined label for the
>   backup. (Typically this would be the name under which the backup dump
>   file will be stored.) When used in exclusive mode, the function writes
>   a backup label file (backup_label) and, if there are any links in the
>   pg_tblspc/ directory, a tablespace map file (tablespace_map) into the
>   database cluster's data directory, performs a checkpoint, and then
>   returns the backup's starting transaction log location as text.

Following the logic the sequence should be this:

- **backup**:

  1. the day before - just before VM copy, run `select pg_start_backup('some label')` (make sure it returned location - it can take long time to make a savepoint, or force fast creation at IO spike price)
  2. VM backup
  3. `select pg_stop_backup()`
- **restore**:

  1. I restored a vm
  2. create recovery.conf with `restore_command = 'cp /.../%f %p'`
  3. rcpostgresql start
  4. let people know if it worked

Also yo might want to read about the pg_control, chechpoints and recover sequence [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/wal-internals.html).

Comment: next incremental backup of the vm is tonight. So i will check it tomorrow.

Comment: cool. thank you. I did very close thing with oracle11 - so curious